# Error message while using Fastlane Spaceship

Tags: ios, ruby, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, fastlane

I´m following "[Automating IAP creation in iTunes Connect](https://goodkindoflazy.com/2017/12/11/automating-iap-creation-in-itunes-connect/)" to connect to iTunes to bulk-create multiple purchase items. I´m using the fastlane gem, but at the beginning, the login command is returning an error:

```
require 'io/console'
require 'spaceship'
require 'csv'

Spaceship::Tunes.login("login", "pass")
```

When I run this code I'm getting these errors:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/spaceship1586831345_16204_22439120.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
        22: from ./test.rb:10:in `<main>'
        21: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/tunes/spaceship.rb:24:in `login'
        20: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:346:in `login'
        19: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:384:in `login'
        18: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:775:in `do_login'
        17: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/tunes/tunes_client.rb:127:in `send_login_request'
        16: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:471:in `send_shared_login_request'
        15: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:682:in `request'
        14: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:791:in `log_request'
        13: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:841:in `extract_key_from_block'
        12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:476:in `block in send_shared_login_request'
        11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:547:in `itc_service_key'
        10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:682:in `request'
          9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:811:in `log_request'
          8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:242:in `logger'
          7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:242:in `new'
          6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:387:in `initialize'
          5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:387:in `new'
          4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:671:in `initialize'
          3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:736:in `set_dev'
          2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:744:in `open_logfile'
          1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:744:in `open'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:744:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/spaceship1586831345_16204_22439120.log (Errno::ENOENT)
        24: from ./test.rb:10:in `<main>'
        23: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/tunes/spaceship.rb:24:in `login'
        22: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:346:in `login'
        21: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:384:in `login'
        20: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:775:in `do_login'
        19: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/tunes/tunes_client.rb:127:in `send_login_request'
        18: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:471:in `send_shared_login_request'
        17: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:682:in `request'
        16: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:791:in `log_request'
        15: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:841:in `extract_key_from_block'
        14: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:476:in `block in send_shared_login_request'
        13: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:547:in `itc_service_key'
        12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:682:in `request'
        11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:811:in `log_request'
        10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:242:in `logger'
          9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:242:in `new'
          8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:387:in `initialize'
          7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:387:in `new'
          6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:671:in `initialize'
          5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:736:in `set_dev'
          4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:742:in `open_logfile'
          3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:746:in `rescue in open_logfile'
          2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:752:in `create_logfile'
          1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:752:in `open'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb:752:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/spaceship1586831345_16204_22439120.log (Errno::ENOENT)
        12: from ./test.rb:10:in `<main>'
        11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/tunes/spaceship.rb:24:in `login'
        10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:346:in `login'
          9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:384:in `login'
          8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:775:in `do_login'
          7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/tunes/tunes_client.rb:127:in `send_login_request'
          6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:471:in `send_shared_login_request'
          5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:682:in `request'
          4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:791:in `log_request'
          3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:841:in `extract_key_from_block'
          2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:476:in `block in send_shared_login_request'
          1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:537:in `itc_service_key'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.145.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:558:in `rescue in itc_service_key': Could not receive latest API key from App Store Connect, this might be a server issue. (Spaceship::AppleTimeoutError)
```

My Apple account already has 2-step verification.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Create the folder tmp in C:/ and it will work